# Redis Mass insertion using pipeline will cause extra bandwidth used in Nodejs

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am developing an application where I am using pipe mode of redis to do hset operation with multiple keys and values all in 1 command. I have seen that it is causing extra bandwidth used on  my server since the data put in memory is totalling to about 300mb.
We know that most of the time there is a bandwidth where we can only send 100mb per second. This issue is causing a lot of latency issues on my server.

To resolve this issue I thought to submit batch hset commands with pipeline. I am pretty unclear if pipeline would send the request all together at the exec() command of nodejs redis client pipeline or will send it separately for all requests but, listen all at once.

I am asking this because if it sends all data together from the TCP stack on our side will again cause the issue of high latency as before.
Please any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline will send all command together to Redis server when execute on client, so it will not solve your problem.

The only suggestion is not send the 300mb data at the same time if possible. You can implement a producer-consumer queue to split the commands.